# R: Plot convex hull with geom_raster

Tags: r, ggplot2

I'm using the code below to plot the given graph:

```
ggplot() + geom_raster(aes(x=X, y=Y, fill=temp), df, show.legend = F)
```

This is what the data looks like:

```
                  X             Y       temp
     1:         0.012          0.016 0.001467175
     2:         0.012          0.018 0.001543842
     3:         0.014          0.018 0.001711704
     4:         0.012          0.020 0.001621719
     5:         0.014          0.020 0.001801149
    ---                                         
371011:         1.618          2.000 0.727286814
371012:         1.620          2.000 0.727429577
371013:         1.622          2.000 0.727548676
371014:         1.624          2.000 0.727639502
371015:         1.626          2.000 0.727697465
```

However, I would like the spiky parts to be removed and only the convex hull plotted. I've tried using slice(chull(X,Y)) but that gives me an empty plot. Could anyone help?

[image]

Comment: Could you edit to make this reproducible, that is, include some data people can use for a solution?

Comment: white parts are there because there is no data in those points. if you want the convex hull to be filled: What colour are those missing points supposed to be?

Comment: I don't want to fill those white parts, but rather remove the spiky blue parts so the boundary looks smooth.